# Aliasing NFS export path

Tags: nfs

Is there a way to define an alias for a NFS-exported directory *directly* inside `/etc/exports` (without using a symlink)?

For example, I want to access this export

```
/home/username/nfsdir 192.168.0.100(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

as `"hostname:/myalias" instead of "hostname:/home/username/nfsdir".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `mount -t bind` to create the "alias".  ie

```
mount -t bind /home/username/nfsdir /myalias
```

and then export /myalias.

To make this permanent, add the following line to your `/etc/fstab`

```
/home/username/nfsdir /myalias bind bind 0 0
```

Comment: Right, but that is the same as creating a symlink. I'm searching for a way to do this using the `/etc/exports` file *only*. Something like the share names in Windows/Samba, which are mapped to real paths.

Comment: Which OS is your nfs server running?  It appears that some nfs servers support a "refer" option which may do what you want.  See "man exports" on your nfs server to see if it supports "refer".

Comment: It's a minimal Debian lenny. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that asap.

Comment: Tried `/myalias 192.168.139.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,refer=/real/directory@192.168.39.129)` (.129 being the NFS server itself) with no success. It keeps showing me the empty directory `/myalias` instead of "forwarding" me to the files in `/real/path`. Can you give me a working example config? (note: I tried it with and without `mount --bind /real/directory /real/directory` as described in the man page)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used the refer option before.  :-(  I saw it there and thought it might be useful to you.

Comment: I have a feeling that you can't do what you want from within    /etc/exports.  However, I can see how to achieve the result you're looking for using NFSv4 and     mount -t bind.  If you're interested, I can show you my NFSv4 configuration.

Comment: @Convict Yes, append it into your answer